# How to get more work items running concurrently in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I set the global work size equal to `{100,10}` and local work size equal to `{1,1}`. It was expected 100*10 work items running concurrently but turned out only ~50 work items.

I wonder how I can get more work items running simultaneously? Is it depending on my code complexity?

Note: I only use ~100 MB global memory and ~100 KB private memory

Comment: Don't use a local worksize of 1. In general, that is literally the worst possible choice for exposing parallelism. What size you choose depends on your hardware. There is plenty of hardware specific information about local worksize selection strategy for the major vendors hardware

Answer (score 0):

Use at least a workgroup size (local size) of 32. In 2D this can be 1x32 or 2x16 or 4x8, but the number of work items in a workgroup must be at least 32, and also a multiple of 32.

The reason for this is that the GPU hardware computes work items in groups of 32 (so-called warps). If you set the workgroup size to only 16, then half of the hardware is idle at any time because only 16 work items are computed in a warp at any time. If you set the work group size to 1, you get only 1/32 of the performance of your GPU.

You can also set work group size to 64, 128, 256 or 512. This may be beneficial if you use local memory explicitly for communications between work items within a workgroup. If you don't use local memory, you can choose work group size to tune for best performance. Out of my experience, across 32, 64, 128 and 256, there is almost no difference.

For good performance, you should also set the global size sufficiently large, at least a few million work items. Otherwise, the GPU may not be saturated and latency for PCIe transfer ia longer than kernel compute times, so overall performance is poor.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I changed local work size into `{16,2}` and global work size into `{64,64}`. I got about ~1500 work items running concurrently (almost 32 times to my former ~50 work items), it is amazing! I only know this `warp` in CUDA but now also in OpenCL : )

Comment: I also wondering how to further increasing the work items? (more than 1500 wi running concurrently) Thank you so so so much!